# Know git hash before committing?

Tags: git, hash

Is there any way to know the hash of the commit before committing?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just commit, get the hash, and then reset --soft?

Comment: I thought doing that, but isn't there a way of doing that instead this proccess?

Comment: There's always a way, but it's a bit of gymnastics.  Why do you need the hash?

Comment: There are good reasons to do that. E.g. you want to embed versioning information in data that your code creates once run after compilation. It seems git isn't built for providing a unique hash for your code. It's evolved so much that it cannot satisfy such a simple feat.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

What possible reason do you have for needing this? If you were thinking of putting the hash of the commit into its own commit message, I'm sorry to tell you but that's impossible (or at least, impossible without breaking SHA1). The commit message is one of the pieces that are used when generating the hash, so any attempt to modify the message would change the hash.

In any case, finding out the hash of the commit before committing is nearly indistinguishable from actually committing, writing down the hash, and then throwing away the commit (as [Carl Norum suggested in his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14208272/know-git-hash-before-committing#comment19702705_14208272)). The reason is that the hash is generated by making the commit object and passing it through SHA1. So in order to find the hash without committing, you'd have to basically walk through the commit process manually and SHA1 the results, without actually writing the object to disk. And not only is that rather impractical, but it's also completely pointless.

Comment: I thought GIT would have a way to do that, just like Subversion does (e.g. $Revision$).

Comment: @MarceloLiberato: In Subversion, it's trivial to predict what the revision number of the commit you're creating is going to be. In git, it's quite literally impossible (again, unless you're proposing to somehow break SHA1).

Comment: And by "impossible" I don't mean "because git doesn't provide a way", I mean "because you cannot possibly implement this functionality, period".

Comment: @MarceloLiberato I have never used Subversion. Can I use subversion on a git repo, for its more proper version numbering, without causing mayhem?

Comment: "What possible reason" would you have for lecturing this person? this is a legitimate question that doesn't need your judging sprinkled in between the actual answer..

Comment: @CatBoss Because the answer to the question "what possible reason do you have for needing this" is what determines if it's impossible or not.

Comment: Is there ant other 1 to 1 identifier I can know before doing the actual commit? I have a binary file I want to say it was created by the state of certain commit. I will push the binary and the commit together.

Comment: @Royi You can get the hash of the binary file, then make the commit, then check that the commit includes that hash. Merely running `git add filename` will add it to the index and then `git ls-files -s filename` will show you the hash in the index. Once you commit, you can then use `git ls-tree commithash` to verify the contents of the tree in that commit and see that the filename still has the same hash.

Comment: @LilyBallard Such functionality certainly can be implemented if the expectation that the SHA is based upon all the tracked content is relaxed. A hypothetical `.gitshaignore` file would be useful for, say, ignoring files that merely provide metadata about the state of the repo, such as https://citation-file-format.github.io/. It is useful to be able to make the commit, edit a citation file to include the commit hash, and then `git commit --amend` without changing the SHA.

Answer (score 18):

The commit hash is dependent of commit time.

If you make 2 commits with same changes, same parent, same author and commit message within the same second, you will get the same hash. Otherwise, the hash should be different.

Answer (score 3):

If you are only interesting in predictable references to commits and do not care about the complete hash, you could customize the short hash (first 4 to 8 characters) after making a commit to whatever you like using [lucky-commit](https://github.com/not-an-aardvark/lucky-commit). This also works on GPG signed commits.

Caveats:

- The more characters you fix at the beginning, the longer it takes, exponentially longer.
- It has to be run after each and every commit
- It will make a duplicate commit for every commit in the local repository. See below example:

```
% git log --oneline --graph         
* 0000003 (HEAD -> master) Third commit
* 0000002 Second commit
* 0000001 First commit
% git log --oneline --graph --reflog
* 4ef3899 Third commit
| * 0000003 (HEAD -> master) Third commit
|/  
* 0000002 Second commit
| * d756f59 Second commit
|/  
* 0000001 First commit
* a1e6be7 First commit
```

---

Finding commit hash before making a commit is possible in theory, but requires in-depth knowledge of git's inner workings and then engineering a solution around it. For a brief overview you can read Git Magic Chapter 8 Secrets Revealed, sections on [Blobs](http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/%7Eblynn/gitmagic/ch08.html#_blobs), [Trees](http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/%7Eblynn/gitmagic/ch08.html#_trees), and [Commits](http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/%7Eblynn/gitmagic/ch08.html#_commits).